Is voting on a post considered modification of that post?
I just logged in to my account after several days and I had received a notification that one of my questions has received two more upvotes in the last 7 days:

But when I clicked on the question link I saw my post has been modified 2 days ago. I checked the timeline but I didn't see any changes in recent days! Also, I have received no notifications about the changes.

So I can think of two possibilities:

The vote is considered a change.
The change has been undone but the modification message below the question title is still there.

Which of the above assumptions is true?

No, voting is not a modification of a post
There was an 'answer' 2 days ago which was deleted because they were being rude to you.
The two upvotes were probably added after question the was bumped to the front page because of the new answer.

You might also want to explain about the timeline feature; https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/118083/timeline
